# Returning Apollo useQuery result from inside a function in Vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vuejs3, apollo-client, vue-composition-api

I'm having some issues finding a clean way of returning results from inside a method to my template using **Apollo v4** and **Vue 3** composition API.

Here's my component:

```js
export default {
    components: {
        AssetCreationForm,
        MainLayout,
        HeaderLinks,
        LoadingButton,
        DialogModal
    },

    setup() {
        const showNewAssetModal = ref(false);

        const onSubmitAsset = (asset) => {
            // how do I access result outside the handler function
            const { result } = useQuery(gql`
                  query getAssets {
                    assets {
                        id
                        name
                        symbol
                        slug
                        logo
                    }
                  }
                `)
            };
        }

        return {
            showNewAssetModal,
            onSubmitAsset,
        }
    },

}
```

The `onSubmitAsset` is called when user clicks on a button on the page.

**How do I return useQuery `result` from the setup function to be able to access it in the template?** (I don't want to copy the value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the `useQuery()` outside of the submit method, as [shown in the docs](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html#usequery). And if you'd like to defer the query fetching until the submit method is called, you can disable the auto-start by passing `enabled:false` as an option (3rd argument of `useQuery`):

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const fetchEnabled = ref(false)
    const { result } = useQuery(gql`...`, null, { enabled: fetchEnabled })

    const onSubmitAsset = (asset) => {
      fetchEnabled.value = true
    }

    return { result, onSubmitAsset }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-apollo-query-graphql?file=src/components/MyForm.vue)

Comment: Much appreciated.